# PHP, ZF: Zend_Acl for module-controller-action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

I need some examples (URLs) for adding Zend_Acl (roles and rules, allowing to visit or deny actions). I've googled but didn't find exactly that I need - step by step guide to provide such operations with module, not just controller-action.

BTW, it's good if in example will be used Zend_Config.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Start by reading the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)

You should at least attempt to solve the problem before asking for others to find articles for you.

But failing that, this is what I do:

- An ACL resource is my module
- An ACL privilege is my controller
- A logged in user has a role
- When checking the ACL for access, use the logged in user's role and use the request object's module and controller for your ACL resource and privilege

Answer (score 0):

Some tutorials here [Zendcasts,com > Access Control](http://www.zendcasts.com/category/screencasts/web-architecture/access-control/) not sure if its what you are looking for, have a look see.